# Adding keyframes with a script

Tags: scripting, keyframes

How to add keyframes to the "Alpha" parameter with a script
regarding "Object Properties" highlighted in the screenshot below?
I would like the script to add a keyframe with the value "1" at the current position of the slider on the timeline and 30 frames later another keyframe with the parameter "0".
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: i think you can't because you also cannot add a "normal" keyframe there via UI. But....you could "rebuild" this easily by using the callbacks described here https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html and then just set the value manually like this: bpy.data.objects["Cube"].color[3]=1